# Parsing XML in Python with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, findall

I'm using the documentation here to try to get only the values (name,ip , netmask) for certain elements.
This is an example of the structure of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:5cf32451-91af-4f71-a0bd-ead244b81b1f">
            <data>
                    <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
                            <interface>
                                    <name>GigabitEthernet1</name>
                                    <type xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type>   
                                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                                    <ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
                                            <address>
                                                    <ip>192.168.40.30</ip>
                                                    <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
                                            </address>
                                    </ipv4>
                                    <ipv6 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip"/>
                            </interface>
                            <interface>
                                    <name>GigabitEthernet2</name>
                                    <type xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type>   
                                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                                    <ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
                                            <address>
                                                    <ip>10.10.10.1</ip>
                                                    <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
                                            </address>
                                    </ipv4>
                                    <ipv6 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip"/>
                            </interface>
                            
                    </interfaces>
            </data>
    </rpc-reply>
```

Python code: This code returns nothing .

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
    tree = ET.parse("C:\\Users\\Redha\\Documents\\test_network\\interface1234.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    namespaces = {'interfaces': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces'  }
    for elem in root.findall('.//interfaces:interfaces', namespaces): 
            s0 = elem.find('.//interfaces:name',namespaces)
            name = s0.text
            print(name)
```

Comment: Don't look from root with `.//` for descendants at a certain node. Try `s0 = elem.find('interfaces:interface/interfaces:name', namespaces)`. However according to this [fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8iu8bbV), original code should output `'GigabitEthernet1'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface = ET.parse('interface2.xml')

interface_root = interface.getroot()

for interface_attribute in interface_root[0][0]:
    print(f"{interface_attribute[0].text}, {interface_attribute[3][0][0].text}, {interface_attribute[3][0][1].text}")
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.